# Почему срабатывает вызов метода без бинда?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Собственно, суть вопроса в заголовке, только начинаю изучать ООП, суть задачи в том, чтобы забиндить изменение положения рук человечка, но почему-то, методы вызываются без бинда.

```
from tkinter import *


class a1:

    def __init__(self, x, y, c):
        self.x = x

        self.y = y

        self.cl = c

    def Body(self):
        self.body = self.cl.create_line(self.x + 25, self.y + 50, self.x + 25, self.y + 200, width=6)
        self.body = self.cl.create_oval(self.x, self.y, self.x + 50, self.y + 50, fill='red')
        self.body = self.cl.create_line(self.x + 25, self.y + 199, self.x - 20, self.y + 255, width=6)
        self.body = self.cl.create_line(self.x + 25, self.y + 199, self.x + 65, self.y + 255, width=6)

    def Arms(self):  # Вниз
        self.armr = self.cl.create_line(self.x + 25, self.y + 60, self.x + 75, self.y + 110, width=6, tag='правая')

        self.arml = self.cl.create_line(self.x + 25, self.y + 60, self.x - 25, self.y + 110, width=6, tag='левая')

    def Arms1(self):  # вверх
        self.armr = self.cl.create_line(self.x + 25, self.y + 60, self.x + 75, self.y, width=6, tag='правая')

        self.arml = self.cl.create_line(self.x + 25, self.y + 60, self.x - 25, self.y, width=6, tag='левая')

    def Arms2(self):  # центр
        self.armr = self.cl.create_line(self.x - 40, self.y + 60, self.x + 90, self.y + 60, width=6, tag='рука')


win = Tk()
win.geometry('500x500')
c = Canvas(win, bg='white', width=500, height=500)
c.pack()
obj = a1(200, 200, c)
obj.Body()
c.bind(1, obj.Arms())
c.bind(2, obj.Arms1())
c.bind(3, obj.Arms2())
win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно передавать функцию, а не вызывать ее в методе `bind`:

```
c.bind(1, obj.Arms)
c.bind(2, obj.Arms1)
c.bind(3, obj.Arms2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Учёл ответы выше и доработал программу, работает только в одну сторону.

```
from tkinter import *


class a1:

    def __init__(self, x, y, c):
        self.x = x

        self.y = y

        self.cl = c

    def Body(self):
        self.body = self.cl.create_line(self.x + 25, self.y + 50, self.x + 25, self.y + 200, width=6)
        self.body = self.cl.create_oval(self.x, self.y, self.x + 50, self.y + 50, fill='red')
        self.body = self.cl.create_line(self.x + 25, self.y + 199, self.x - 20, self.y + 255, width=6)
        self.body = self.cl.create_line(self.x + 25, self.y + 199, self.x + 65, self.y + 255, width=6)

    def Arms(self, x):  # Вниз
        self.armr = self.cl.create_line(self.x + 25, self.y + 60, self.x + 75, self.y + 110, width=6, tag='правая')

        self.arml = self.cl.create_line(self.x + 25, self.y + 60, self.x - 25, self.y + 110, width=6, tag='левая')

    def Arms1(self, x):  # вверх
        self.armr = self.cl.create_line(self.x + 25, self.y + 60, self.x + 75, self.y, width=6, tag='правая')

        self.arml = self.cl.create_line(self.x + 25, self.y + 60, self.x - 25, self.y, width=6, tag='левая')

    def Arms2(self, x):  # центр
        self.armr = self.cl.create_line(self.x - 40, self.y + 60, self.x + 90, self.y + 60, width=6, tag='рука')


win = Tk()
win.geometry('500x500')
c = Canvas(win, bg='white', width=500, height=500)
c.pack()
obj = a1(200, 200, c)
obj.Body()
c.bind("<Button-1>", obj.Arms)
c.bind("<Button-2>", obj.Arms1)
c.bind("<Button-3>", obj.Arms2)
win.mainloop()
```